# I installed Python for all users (Windows 10) but it still created a user installation

Tags: python, pip

I'm not sure I understand what's going on here, since I create a virtual environment and it seems to be using the "all users" installation, but whenever I update pip, it does so in a user-specific folder?

I've just installed the latest Python version (using the Windows installer from python.org). I carefully selected the custom installation option and selected to add Python to environment variables and "install for all users", so I saw how the default user folder changed to C:\Program Files\Python39, as seen here:
[image: python installation]

Then I tried to update pip (from version 21.1.1 to 21.1.2) so I ran `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and got this message:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not
> writeable Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\program
> files\python39\lib\site-packages (21.1.1) Collecting pip   Using
> cached pip-21.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB) Installing collected
> packages: pip   WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe
> are installed in
> 'C:\Users\Currentuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\Scripts' which is
> not on PATH.   Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you
> prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
> Successfully installed pip-21.1.2 WARNING: You are using pip version
> 21.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe -m pip install
> --upgrade pip' command.

So what's with this `C:\Users\Currentuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39` folder?

If I run pip --version` I get:

> pip 21.1.2 from
> C:\Users\Currentuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pip
> (python 3.9)

So it looks like it has created a user-only installation in `C:\Users\Currentuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39`?

The problem is that now I have 2 versions, and venv uses the old one. I created a `C:\Users\Currentuser\Desktop\test` folder and then created a virtual environment within it. In this environment, `pip list` shows me it uses the old pip version:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        21.1.1
setuptools 56.0.0
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\currentuser\desktop\test\my-venv\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So how do I prevent Python from using this `C:\Users\Currentuser\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39` folder and force it to use the `C:\Program Files\Python39\` I installed to?